# Get records modified by SF Data Loader App (or get history of jobs on it)

Tags: soql, data-loader, upsert

I did some bulk `upserts` using csvs and SF Data Loader. However, my formatting was off for my `external Id` and "duplicate" records were created instead.

Is there a simple option to revert jobs done in the Data Loader app?

If not, is there a way to get like a `jobId` or something and use that to bulk Delete.

In soql, I think I can easily do this by just using createdBy(user logged in Data Loader App) and where createdDate is when I used the app. However, just wondering if there was some better exact way to do a clean reversal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no option available to revert or undo. But you can easily delete the records using the success file with DataLoader.

Generally Data Loader generates two CSV output files that contain the results of the operation. The success file contains the Ids of the records successfully created/updated. Using this success file you can delete the records.

Be careful, as you have done upsert operation the success file may have some existing records based on your criteria.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Unfortunately, I deleted the success files. My Soql query should suffice though

Comment: You should always keep these files along with the Original CSV file for audit purposes after every Data Load.